# GCM Push Notifications not opening app

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Whenever a gcm message comes back to my phone, I receive a notification. However, when I press it, it doesn't open my app. It only disappears. Previously when I used `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT`, it would work, but if I sent multiple messages, it wouldn't be up to date. Please help.

This is my notification code

```
public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends IntentService{


//set ID for the notification, so it can be updated
public static final int notifyID = 9001;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    Log.d("GCMN","GCMNTEST");
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
                    + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Message Received from Google GCM Server:\n\n"
                        + extras.get(AppConstants.MSG_KEY));
        }
    }
    GCMBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

private void sendNotification(String msg){

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    Log.d("RECEIVEDPT2",msg);
    resultIntent.putExtra("msg", msg);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,resultIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setContentTitle("Alert")
            .setContentTitle("You've received a new message")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_cast_dark);

    //Set pending intent
    mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    //Set vibration
    int defaults = 0;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    mNotifyBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);
    // Set the content for Notification
    mNotifyBuilder.setContentText("You have new notifications");
    // Set autocancel
    mNotifyBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    // Post a notification
    mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, mNotifyBuilder.build());

}
}
```

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.amosang.pushtest" >


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<!-- GCM Permissions - Start here -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.amosang.pushtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.amosang.pushtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:exported="true"
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <action android:name="com.example.amosang.pushtest" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".GCMNotificationIntentService" />

    <activity
        android:name=".NewRequest"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_request" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

I can't seem to add FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK as it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is tested code that will help you to achieve the desired result.

```
private void notify(String msg) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Title")
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{5000})
                    .setLights(Color.GREEN, 3000, 3000) //for notification led light with color
                    .setContentText(msg)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(soundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

Comment: Hello, does this cause the notifications to stack up or does this just replace every new one?

Comment: Hi,as we have a notification id 0.So when ever it will be called it will replace previous one.If you want to have new every time,then you should have a new notification id.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
`PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`
```

instead of

```
`PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);`
```

Please add `android:exported="true"` [http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html] in android manifest inside activity tag which is supposed to be opened after tapping  notification from status bar.

Comment: Hello, I can't seem to find flag activity new task. Must I import a jar in?

Comment: Also, When I placed the android:exported true without changing the pending intent, the app started, but my message wasn't shown for some reason.